# Print elements of vector in single line

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement, vector

I have a dataframe with 12 rows and two columns one with dates and the other with temperatures.
I want to extract the values that meet the criteria in my if-statement (temperature is smaller than or equal to -20). This is my code:

```
for (row in 1:12) {
  T <- winter[row, 2]
  
  if(T <= -20) {
    x <-c(winter[row,2])
    print(x)
  }
}
```

Print x gives me this:

```
[1] -27
[1] -21
[1] -24
[1] -34
[1] -20
```

But I want something like this:

```
[1] -27, -21, -24, -34, -20
```

Dput:

```
dput(winter)
structure(list(date = 1:12, temp = c(-27L, -21L, -8L, -12L, 
-10L, -24L, 8L, -7L, -34L, -19L, -2L, -20L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Comment: Don't use `print` to generate output. Instead, save your results to an object. (Also, I recommend not using `T` as a variable name, as it is shorthand for `TRUE`.)

Comment: @Axeman How do I save to an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of vectorized conditional indexing (basically just figure out which rows you want):

```
mask <- winter[1:12, 2] <= -20

winter[mask, "temp"]
# [1] -27 -21 -24 -34 -20
```

This is sometimes referred to as a "boolean mask", although that's a more common term in Python.  You can read up on this indexing method in R in section 4.5.7 of Hadley's "Advanced R" book, [here](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/subsetting.html#selecting-rows-based-on-a-condition-logical-subsetting).